# Making a zip code choropleth in R using ggplot2 and ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, choropleth, choroplethr

I am trying to make a choropleth of very simple data, and it's kind of a pain in the neck. I have the following zip codes in the Eastern USA. This is made up data but you get the idea.

```
Zip    Freq
11101    10
10014    15
11238   400
```

etc. for about 100 rows. Values of Freq range from 0-1000, and these are the ones I would like to use to determine the color of each zipcode. I would ideally also like the map to focus on the Eastern USA instead of the whole country.

I want to make a choropleth with this data and each zip code but I can't figure out how to import zip code shapefiles. I have tried [this tutorial](http://notesofdabbler.bitbucket.org/2013_12_censusBlog/censusHomeValueExplore_wdesc.html) but I got an error at the fortify() step that I can't get beyond. I'm not sure if that tutorial's method is even the best way to go about it.

ggplot2 seems to come with State and County, but I can't figure out how to map by zip code. (Eventually I am going to map by census tract but right now I just want to learn how to use shapefiles for zip codes and this simple data set)

All the resources I have found for choroplethr use functions that are now deprecated. I spent hours chasing my tail in an effort to use it, and am so frustrated, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this package. it makes it easy to do what you want http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/choroplethr.pdf

Comment: Thank you for responding. Choroplethr's function for doing this, zip_map, is deprecated in the current version. When I try to use it I get the message "This function is deprecated as of choroplethr version 3.0.0.   Please use ?zip_choropleth instead." But when I try to use zip_choropleth, it says that function does not exist!

Comment: oh, i think it branched off into a separate package: https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethrZip

Comment: This is not available through R yet. At least I tried installing choroplethrZip and it said it was not available. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you don't need to *fill* the zips, you could use [this technique](http://www.r-bloggers.com/my-first-r-package-zipcode/). Here is a [nice tutorial](http://www.kevjohnson.org/making-maps-in-r/) which appears to be updated. Some (myself included) would argue that "filled" maps are misleading as some large (area) zip codes are not densely populated - this creates a bias in interpretation - thus packages such as  [rcstatebin](https://github.com/ramnathv/rcstatebin) have been created.

Comment: did you do this `# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.3.0')`? it's not on cran.

Comment: Isn't it unsafe to install something that isn't on cran? And @JasonAizkalns, thanks for replying. I am trying to use that method right now but running into trouble with gpclibPermitStatus() and then when I try to insteall gpclib it says "Package which is only available in source form.....These will not be installed." It sucks that this is such an opaque, abysmally documented process. But I appreciate your guidance

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093399/how-to-turn-gpclibpermit-to-true) shld help with the `gpclibPermitStatus` issue. The `choroplethZip` package is safe to use and is probably the easiest way for you to do what you need to do unless you want an end-to-end example on doing it manually in `ggplot` (from shapefile to choropleth).

Comment: @hrbrmstr thank you for trying, but as I addressed above, install.packages("gpclib") returns an error message that is "is only available in source form." I was hoping to use this as a learning process, so an end-to-end example would be very helpful

Comment: What's wrong with installing from source? `install.packages("gpclib", type="source")`. Just grab [RTools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) if you're on Windows.

Comment: See, why didn't I think of that? That is exactly what I needed to do, but I didn't know you could do that with install.packages. Onwards! (Also, feel free to post that answer in the separate question I asked about this issue). Thank you @hrbrmstr!!

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for using `choroplethr`, and I'm sorry that the deprecation of `zip_map` caused you problems. I have moved all ZIP related functions to a separate packaged called [choroplethrZip](https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethrZip).

The old verion of choroplethr rendered ZIPs as scatterplots, not choropleths. Rendering them as proper choropleths required a map that is too large for CRAN (~60MB), which is why it is only available via github.

The github page I link to above has 3 vignettes. Basically, the function `zip_choropleth` should do exactly what you want, and work like all the other `choroplethr` functions. You want to use the `state_zoom` to zoom in on the east coast states:

```
# use the devtools package from CRAN to install choroplethrZip from github
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.3.0')
library(choroplethrZip)

data(df_pop_zip)

# ec = east coast
ec_states = c("maine", "new hampshire", "massachusetts", "rhode island", "connecticut", 
              "new york", "new jersey", "delaware", "maryland", 
              "virginia", "north carolina", "south carolina", "georgia", "florida",
              "pennsylvania", "district of columbia", "vermont", "west virginia")

zip_choropleth(df_pop_zip, 
               state_zoom = ec_states, 
               title      = "2012 ZCTA Population Estimates",
               legend     = "Population") + coord_map()
```

[image]

The resulting map is essentially unreadable because the zips are so small that all you can see are the borders. If you want to remove the borders, try this:

```
choro = choroplethrZip::ZipChoropleth$new(df_pop_zip)
choro$prepare_map()

data(zip.regions)
choro$legend = "Population"
ec_zips = zip.regions[zip.regions$state.name %in% ec_states, "region"]
ec_df   = choro$choropleth.df[choro$choropleth.df$region %in% ec_zips, ]
ec_plot = choro$render_helper(ec_df, "", choro$theme_clean()) + 
              ggtitle("2012 ZCTA Population Estimates")

ec_plot + coord_map()
```

[image]

In the future, I might add an option that makes it easier to render the maps with no borders. But for now (version 1.3.0) this is the easiest way I can see to do it, and is basically what I do behind the scenes to render the national zip maps, which themselves are rendered without borders.

Note that `coord_map` just forces a mercator projection.

Comment: note as of August 2020, 1.5.0 is out, so `install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')` now