# tract_choropleth for NY data

Tags: r, choroplethr

I'm trying to replicate the map shown in Ari's [ACS talk](https://arilamstein.com/census-conference-recording/?tl_inbound=1&tl_target_all=1&tl_form_type=1&tl_period_type=3) using tract_choropleth. However, the codes keep returning an Error message. I have requested the api key and other functions like state_choropleth() and county_choropleth() were working just fine.

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
#api.key.install(DONE)

ny_tract = get_tract_demographics("new york", endyear = 2015)
ny_tract$value = ny_tract$per_capita_income

tract_choropleth(ny_tract, state_name="new york", title='2015 map of NY', 
legend = "dollars", num_colors = 1, county_zoom = 36061)
```

The Error message is

```
Error in maptools::unionSpatialPolygons(cp, attr[,region]): isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE
```

I can see that the data frame ny_tract was loaded with many NA introduced by coercion warnings.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a typo in your question. You wrote `tract_cholopleth` when you meant to write `tract_choropleth`. I tried to edit it, but it said "edits must be at least 6 characters".

Comment: Yes, it is a typo and I changed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to `gpclibPermitStatus()` returning FALSE.

Unfortunately, this is a common error that comes up when working with choroplethr. I once gave a lengthy answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093399/how-to-turn-gpclibpermit-to-true/22261385).

The short answer is to type the following:

```
install.packages("gpclib")
library(maptools)
gpclibPermit()
```

Comment: For anyone else reading as well - on Windows I had to install RTools to compile gpclib, and once that completed this answer worked.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a mac, but it's good to know how it works with Windows.